How to delete a specific question-response pair from a local vector database?
I have implemented a feedback-based chatbot that stores question-response pairs in a local vector database. I am using the following setup to access the vector database:
import os

VECTOR_DB_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "vectordb")

The vector database is being used to store embeddings and responses for efficient similarity searches. Now, I want to delete a specific question-response pair from the vector database. I am aware of the pair that I want to delete (e.g., question: "How are you?", response: "I'm fine, thank you!"), but I am unsure how to remove it programmatically from the database.
Here are a few details about my setup:
The vector database library I'm using is FAISS.
The embeddings for the questions are stored in the database for retrieval.
I can access and query the vector database successfully.
the libraries i am using are
import json
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
import boto3
import botocore
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

What is the best way to locate and delete a specific pair from the vector database?
